# Xcode 6 reporting invalid app id

Tags: xcode, xcode6, xcode-organizer

I can archive a project for the Appstore using XCode 6. But when trying to verify it in Organizer, I get this error message. I get the message with every project/target I've tried to verify using Xcode 6.

Using XCode 5 there's no issue. So recently I've been building with XCode 6, and submitting to Appstore with XCode 5.
Since the deadline for build-only with XCode 6 is approaching, I really need to solve this.

As far as I know, there's no invalid characters in the app id's. Why XCode 6 is reporting the app id as "Xcode iOS App ID com.mybundle *", I don't know.

Anyone else been seeing this behaviour, and have a solution?

[image: XCode 6 error message]

Answer (score 0):

The App ID string contains two parts separated by a period (.)—an App ID Prefix that is defined as your Team ID by default and an App ID Suffix that is defined as a Bundle ID search string. Each part of an App ID has different and important uses for your app.
And Apple recommend using a reverse-domain name style string (i.e., com.domainname.appname). IT CANNOT CONTAIN AN `ASTERISK (*)`.